# isDirtyBox and isDirtyLegend

Tags: highcharts

I found in few of the previous posts like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947484/dynamically-modifying-the-highchart-layout-options), making use of the **`chart.isDirtyBox`** and **`chart.isDirtyLegend`** properties. I could not find them in the highcharts API either.

What actually do they do ? Can anybody out there help me get the documentation for these properties or help me explaining the use of these properties, possibly with examples?

Comment: The answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915154/what-does-redraw-exactly-do may help. This talks mainly about series.isDirty, the same concept can be extended to legends and the chart container(box)

Comment: Remember that these options are not part of official API, so using them is little hacky. It may be changed any time to other name or even removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not on documentation, it's only internaly used to know which elements have been changed and have to be redraw.

**Highstock v1.2.4**

**isDirtyBox** - Relevant code.

```
var chart = this,
    ...
    isDirtyBox = chart.isDirtyBox;

// redraw axes
each(axes, function (axis) {

    // Fire 'afterSetExtremes' only if extremes are set
    if (axis.isDirtyExtremes) { // #821
        axis.isDirtyExtremes = false;
        afterRedraw.push(function () { // prevent a recursive call to chart.redraw() (#1119)
            fireEvent(axis, 'afterSetExtremes', axis.getExtremes()); // #747, #751
        });
    }

    if (axis.isDirty || isDirtyBox || hasStackedSeries) {
        axis.redraw();
        isDirtyBox = true; // #792
    }
});

// the plot areas size has changed
if (isDirtyBox) {
    chart.drawChartBox();
}
```

**isDirtyLegend** - Relevant code.

```
var chart = this,
    ...
    redrawLegend = chart.isDirtyLegend,
    ...

// handle updated data in the series
each(series, function (serie) {
    if (serie.isDirty) { // prepare the data so axis can read it
        if (serie.options.legendType === 'point') {
            redrawLegend = true;
        }
    }
});

// handle added or removed series
if (redrawLegend && legend.options.enabled) { // series or pie points are added or removed
    // draw legend graphics
    legend.render();

    chart.isDirtyLegend = false;
}
```

`isDirtyLegend` is also used in `chart.resize`, `series.remove` and `chart.addSeries` with the following line.

```
chart.isDirtyLegend = true; // force legend redraw
```